# Unmapping Treemacs `<prior>` and `<next>` (Page up and Page down)

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, treemacs

I'm trying to unmap the `<next>` and `<prior>` key-bindings from Treemacs, because I find counterintuitive that it's the only place where they scroll a different window instead of the current one.

I've found that they are mapped inside keymap `treemacs-mode-map`, so in my `.spacemacs` user-config section I call this:

```lisp
  (with-eval-after-load 'treemacs
    (unbind-key (kbd "<next>") treemacs-mode-map)
    (unbind-key (kbd "<prior>") treemacs-mode-map))
```

But when I try to open the treemacs panel I get this error message:

```
Wrong type argument: stringp, [next]
```

I also tried with `(unbind-key <next>`  or `(unbind-key next` or `(kbd "PageDown"` and nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section of the docstring of `bind-key`:

> KEY-NAME may be a vector, in which case it is passed straight to
>   ‘define-key’. Or it may be a string to be interpreted as
>   spelled-out keystrokes, e.g., "C-c C-z". See documentation of
>   ‘edmacro-mode’ for details.

So simply use `(unbind-key "<next>" treemacs-mode-map)` instead of `(unbind-key (kbd "<next>") treemacs-mode-map)`.